# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folium.plugins'; 'folium' is not a package

Tags: python, folium

I know this question has been asked around quite a few times but none of the solutions have helped me out so far.

I am getting the following error whenever I try running my python script:

```
M-MBP:folder m$ python3.7 folium.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "folium.py", line 3, in <module>
    import folium
  File "/Users/m/folder/folium.py", line 4, in <module>
    from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folium.plugins'; 'folium' is not a package
```

Notes:

- I am running Python3.7, installed via **Homebrew**;
- I've tried installing Folium via **pip**, **conda**, and **cloning its Git repo** directly to my site-packages folder.

None have worked. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is named the same as the package you want.  It's trying to import itself and it doesn't have `plugins` within it.  Name your script something other than `folium.py` and I believe your problem will disappear.

Demonstrated:

```
arts@support:~ 0$ python3
Python 3.4.9 (default, Aug 14 2018, 21:28:57)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import logging
>>> logging.DEBUG
10
>>>
arts@support:~ 0$ cd tmp
arts@support:~/tmp 0$ python3
Python 3.4.9 (default, Aug 14 2018, 21:28:57)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import logging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/arts/tmp/logging.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(logging.DEBUG)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DEBUG'
>>>
arts@support:~/tmp 0$ cat logging.py
import sys
import logging    # Imports itself
import os

print(logging.DEBUG)
```

The reason is, you need to look at `sys.path`

```
arts@support:~/tmp 0$ python3
Python 3.4.9 (default, Aug 14 2018, 21:28:57)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/lib64/python34.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.4', '/usr/lib64/python3.4/plat-linux', '/usr/lib64/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
>>> del sys.path[0]
>>> sys.path
['/usr/lib64/python34.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.4', '/usr/lib64/python3.4/plat-linux', '/usr/lib64/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
>>> import logging
>>> logging.DEBUG
10
>>>
arts@support:~/tmp 0$ python3
Python 3.4.9 (default, Aug 14 2018, 21:28:57)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib64/python34.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.4', '/usr/lib64/python3.4/plat-linux', '/usr/lib64/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
>>> import logging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/arts/tmp/logging.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(logging.DEBUG)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DEBUG'
>>>
```

In this second chunk, you'll see that I deleted the first chunk of the list.  This removes your CURRENT DIRECTORY from python's import path, so it now ignored my `logging.py` file and successfully imported the real `logging` module.

Comment: You are totally right. Thank you!